How to quickly select a particular file in the File Picker dialogue box in MacOS Sequoia
Scenario: I press Cmd+O or File>OpenFile to open a file in a program, say MS Word. The program shows me a file-picker (similar to a finder window), say, open at the Downloads folder.
But the file I want to choose is located at Documents>projects>book>chapter>chapterone.docx, among fifty such documents. How can I navigate to the specific file I want in the file-picker quickly?
Similar scenarios can be found whenever the user wants to locate a specific file located deep inside the file system in a file-picker dialogue box.
